# Cómo resolver esta excepción: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out?

Tags: java, webservice, websocket

Tengo un servicio web que envía transacciones a la red ethereum, tengo este servicio web desplegado en un servidor tomcat9, por cada transacción que envía tendré como respuesta el txHash de esa transacción, toma entre 20 a 120 segundos la respuesta. En el momento en que hice la prueba en el Soapui no hubo ningún problema, pero algunas transacciones respondieron con lentitud, pero como dije antes, soy consciente de esa demora, entonces el sopaui me muestra esa excepción. Entonces quise saber en qué parte tendría que configurar el tiempo de espera, en el servicio web o en el servidor tomcat.

Estoy usando apache tomcat 9

server.xml

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

Comment: Serviría de mucho ver la configuración de tu server.xml.  
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
               minProcessors="3"
               maxProcessors="8"
               maxThreads="20"
               connectionTimeout="150000" 
               asyncTimeout="150000" /> Quizás tengas que aumentar el valor de asyncTimeout. Este solo es un ejemplo.

Comment: Ese archivo seria del tomcat, cierto?

Comment: Si amigo es archivo es de Tomcat. Seguramente hará falta ver tu versión de Tomcat.

Comment: Ahora subir el archivo server.xml

Comment: Así es, es un archivo server.xml. En asyncTimeout podrías colocar un valor que te puede servir.